# destructor is called twice for std::vector with optimization level 0

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I am trying to understand the assembly code generated for the `std::vector` and its `emplace_back (or) push_back` function using [compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/G2tM3z).

**Note: Optimization level is 0 i.e., -O0 is used**

One thing that I couldn't understand is that why are there two destructors being called instead of one (As you can see only one vector is being created. If I assume that a temporary object is being created internally, then atlease I have to see a call to `std::vector` constructor.

This is same with clang compiler as well.

Can someone please explain what is happening here?

Edit 1:

```
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec.emplace_back(10);
}
```

Edit 2:
    Removed the screenshot as it is hard to read it.

Comment: please include code, not pictures of code. This is very hard to read

Comment: Link gives: `Compilation failed`

Comment: It doesn't call the destructor twice, there is an unconditional jump on line 27.

Comment: yes, there is an unconditional jump but there is `ret` statement in the `.L7` and the execution continous.

Comment: I am just trying to see what are the compiler optimizations performed with and without oprimization levels. This is just for learning purposes.

Comment: I do not understand why I got the negative votes for this question. It's a genuine question which is not on the stack overflow. Does asking a question on stackoverflow for learning pruposes is prohibited or what?

Comment: i didnt downvote, but imho screenshots instead of code (half fixed now) and a wrong link (fixed by now) is worth a downvote ;)

Comment: That is the reason I added the code later and the screenshot is to highlight the issue. IMHO, if you feel that the post can be edited, you can suggest the changes and if the user still refuses to edit the post then it's worth the downvote. Anyhow this is just an opinion. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @gurram 1) The votes on the question represents how useful/correct the question is _right now_, not how it might be after indeterminate amount of time. The downvotes can be retracted, once the problems are resolved. 2) "_That is the reason I added the code later and the screenshot is to highlight the issue._" Code can't be read as clearly, when it's a screenshot (and I, personally, refuse to read such code on principle). There are methods of highlighting issue, in textual form. So, "needing to highlight" is not an excuse for posting screenshots of text.

Comment: @gurram yeah, my idea of a perfect downvoting system would include that the downvoter gives a reason for the downvote and if the OP edits the post they get the list of reasons and checks the ones they think are fixed, downvoters would get notified, can review the question again and eventually retract the downvote, but maybe I am dreaming too much and anyhow thats  a topic for elsewhere

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius -> Yes, it do make sense but just downvoting doesn't help if there is no reason mentioned for downvote. This way a you are encouraging the user to do a better post next time. Any how thanks for the explanation. I will try to make the posts better next time.

Comment: @user463035818 -> I do agree with you on this. Thanks

Comment: @gurram "_Yes, it do make sense but just downvoting doesn't help if there is no reason mentioned for downvote._" Yes, I agree with that, and didn't argue against that. Typical reason, why someone might not comment after downvoting, is because someone else posted a comment, with the same reason for downvoting. That's why, as user463035818 mentioned, there should be an automatic notification, sent to all downvoters, upon edits of the question, but some people might view the increased amount of notifications as spam.. There is no perfect system :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a clue at line 34: `call _Unwind_Resume`. That block of code, from lines 28 through 34, is for stack unwinding when an exception is thrown. The normal code path goes through the destructor call at line 25, then, at line 27, jumps past the exception code, to line 35, and from there it returns from the function.

Just to clarify, there's magic here: the call to `_Unwind_Resume` does not return to the caller. It's a trick, to get the address of the block that was being executed, so that the exception handling code can figure out where it was and continue up the stack.

Comment: Just for my clarification (maybe a dumb question). As you mentioned, "The normal code path goes through the destructor call at line 25, then, at line 27, jumps past the exception code, to line 35, and from there it returns from the function." Once returned from the function, doesn't the execution continue again from Line 28.

Comment: @gurram -- no, the normal return from the function returns to whoever called that function. There are no direct execution paths to the code that starts at line 28. Getting there is part of the exception implementation; there's a table of code blocks, one per function, that have to be executed during stack unwinding. It's the stack unwinding code that executes that block. Again, that's magic. Don't look behind the curtain. <g>

Comment: Sorry but still it doesn't make sense to me. My understanding is that the `OS` calls the `main` function label which starts the sequential execution of the assembly instructions (unless there is a branch / jump statement). Unless there is no `ret` statement, the functions will return to the caller, in this case `main` called the `.L7`. So once the `.L7` execution is completed, it returns back to the next instruction after the jump statement in the `main` and continues the execution of the statements further. Please correct my understanding if something is wrong.

Comment: @ Pete Becker --> what kind of magic are we talking here? If possible, can you please kindly suggest some links / docs where I can read more about this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @gurram -- a **jump** statement is **not** a function call. It just says "instead of executing the next instruction, go to `.L7`. A function call says "make a note of where you are now, and jump to this label". Making that note is the key: a function call sets up a return to the address after the call. A jump does not.